# Webdriver executeScript command makes firefox irresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

WebDriver->I am trying to capture the 'date' selected from a UI-Calender. I want to find the 'date' element selected using javascript.For which I used the following :

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('#abc')");

String s=element.getAttribute("value");

System.out.println("  "+s);
```

But strangely when I add the above lines, Firefox stops responding, then script stops working .Version firefox:3.6

Comment: Found something Intresting on using chromedriver a failure trace is shown "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement".

Comment: that's because `executeScript` doesn't return `WebElement` - it's for executing JavaScript. Why don't you do `find_element(By.id("abc")).getAttribute("value")`

Comment: Yes!! I know find elements but the point here is can't we identify an element using javascript/jQuery the webdriver documentation suggests we can do it......[link]http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `return $('#abc')` returns an array of DOM elements. You should use `return $('#abc')[0]`.

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('#abc')[0]");
```